# Machine Learning for analyzing and generating sentences from given text inputs

Tags: nlp, rnn, machine-translation

I'm trying to create a program that will translate Sign Language to Text and apply NLP so that the text is understandable to human. I've used CNN for recognizing sign language but I don't know how to transform the recognized text into a natural language. The idea is given a set of text, I want it to transform it to human language. For example, the statement "Me eat" (texts after recognizing the sign language), I want to improve it to become "I am eating". Can it be done using RNN or does it fall under Machine Translation?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I think this is considered MT indeed. I'm not knowledgeable about this but it seems that there are [many papers published on the topic](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2020&q=sign+language+machine+translation&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).